# Getting Forbidden issue When i Calling The API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on integrating QuickBooks Online in my .net core 3.1 application. for reference, I am using the .net MVC-based project. I have integrated the .net MVC APP to .net core but When I calling the API it's showing Forbidden how can I fix it??

Comment: You also get this error when you request incorrect http verb for example the api require Post and you call it using GET

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden is actually a response code when you are not authenticated. To resolve this, first, you need to think about security. if u really want to secure the endpoints. unless u don't do that everyone can access your API after you deployed it. But, For now in order to remove the authentication. Just go to the Startup Class and look at the ConfigureServices method. there will be something like services.AddAuthendication(opt => {}). this is basically configuring the authentication options such as IDP. So, remove the entire this in order to disable the authentication from your service.

Comment: In Web config file when i use following code


<intuit>
    <ipp>
      <service>
        
        <baseUrl qbo="https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/" />
       
      </service>
    </ipp>
  </intuit>

then its working.  same setting i need to implement in my asp.net core project so there is no web config file so how can i use this code